# Python: sort lists in dictonary of lists, where one list is a key to sorting

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

lets say I have a dictonary

```
d = {
u'a': [1, 4, 6, 7],
u'b': [9, 9, 9, 8],
u'c': ['g', 'a', 'b', '9'],
u'd': [5, 1, 10, 2],
}
```

I want to sort simultaneously lists inside that dictionary, where a key to sorting is an value on list `d[u'd']`
lets say, that result of sorting will be

```
new_d = {
u'a': [4, 7, 1, 6],
u'b': [9, 8, 9, 9],
u'c': ['a', '9', 'g', 'b'],
u'd': [1, 2, 5, 10] <- we have sorted by that list
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from operator import itemgetter
srt_key = [i for i, e in sorted(enumerate(d["d"]), key=itemgetter(1))]

new_d = {}

for k,v in d.items():
    new_d[k] = list(itemgetter(*srt_key)(v))

print(new_d)
{'c': ['a', '9', 'g', 'b'], 'a': [4, 7, 1, 6], 'b': [9, 8, 9, 9], 'd': [1, 2, 5, 10]}
```

Or using a dict comp:

```
new_d = {k: list(itemgetter(*srt_key)(v)) for k,v in d.items()}

print(new_d)
```

Comment: Nice, but this will fail if there are repeated values in the key list.

Comment: @tobias_k, yep realised that, have a work around, just trying to make it a little nicer

Comment: How about `srt_key = [i for i, e in sorted(enumerate(d["d"]), key=itemgetter(1))]`?

Answer (score 4):

First, separate keys and values in the dict

```
>>> keys, values = zip(*d.items())
```

Now, `zip` the values, adding the key-list as the first column

```
>>> zip(d[u"d"], *values)
[(5, 1, 'g', 9, 5), (1, 4, 'a', 9, 1), (10, 6, 'b', 9, 10), (2, 7, '9', 8, 2)]
```

Sort the values by first column (the key-list)

```
>>> sorted(_)
[(1, 4, 'a', 9, 1), (2, 7, '9', 8, 2), (5, 1, 'g', 9, 5), (10, 6, 'b', 9, 10)]
```

Then `zip` the result of the sort back and strip the key-column

```
>>> zip(*_)[1:]
[(4, 7, 1, 6), ('a', '9', 'g', 'b'), (9, 8, 9, 9), (1, 2, 5, 10)]
```

`zip` again with the keys to reconstruct the dictionary.

```
>>> dict(zip(keys, _))
{u'a': (4, 7, 1, 6),
 u'b': (9, 8, 9, 9),
 u'c': ('a', '9', 'g', 'b'),
 u'd': (1, 2, 5, 10)}
```

Everything put together:

```
keys, values = zip(*d.items())
new_d = dict(zip(keys, zip(*sorted(zip(d[u"d"], *values)))[1:]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build `new_d` like this:

```
In [9]: new_d = {}

In [10]: for k in d.keys():
    new_d[k] = [x for (y,x) in sorted(zip(d[u'd'],d[k]), key=lambda pair: pair[0])]
   ....:     

In [11]: new_d
Out[11]: 
{u'a': [4, 7, 1, 6],
 u'b': [9, 8, 9, 9],
 u'c': ['a', '9', 'g', 'b'],
 u'd': [1, 2, 5, 10]}
```

This approach pairs the items from each list with the list governing the sort order, and sorts the list of pairs by the latter.